# How can I write an xpath for prefix "tns"?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have 3 file

1- file (XSD)

```
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://ex.com/baseballplayers" 
    xmlns:nttbp="http://www.ex.com/baseballplayers" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <!-- I put this in here to act as a root element for the XML file -->
        <xs:element name="M1"/>

        <xs:element name="players">
....
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:srting"></xs:attribute>
    </players>
```

2-file (XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="baseballplayers.xsl" ?>    
<nttbp:M1 xmlns:nttbp="http://www.ex.org/M1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ex.org/M1 baseballplayers.xsd ">
        <nttbp:players name="John"></nttbp:players>
```

3- file (XSL)

when I tried to write an XSL file, I do not know how to write the Xpath for the element "players" and its attribute "name", I tried to write it like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="../nttbp:players">
```

but in the browser shows me this message

> Error loading stylesheet: An unknown error has occurred ()

Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the namespace in the stylesheet heading

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:nttbp="http://www.ex.org/M1">
```